# Changing EXIF thumbnail in VB.net under Windows XP

Tags: vb.net, thumbnails, exif

I built an app that makes some modifications to a picture, changes it's EXIF thumbnail to match the newly created picture and saves it.

It works perfectly under Win 7, but under XP, the EXIF thumbnail remains the same. Here is the part of the code that changes the thumbnail.

```
        Dim MS As New MemoryStream()

        Dim bmp_thumb = bmp.GetThumbnailImage(160, 120, Nothing, New IntPtr())

        bmp_thumb.Save(MS, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        bmp_thumb.Dispose()

        MS.Position = 0
        Dim smallthumbbytes As Byte() = MS.ToArray()

        Dim PropertyItems = bmp.PropertyItems
        PropertyItems(0).Id = &H501B
        PropertyItems(0).Type = 1
        PropertyItems(0).Len = smallthumbbytes.Length
        PropertyItems(0).Value = smallthumbbytes
        bmp.SetPropertyItem(PropertyItems(0))

        PropertyItems = bmp.PropertyItems
        PropertyItems(0).Id = &H5023
        PropertyItems(0).Type = CShort(3)
        PropertyItems(0).Len = 2
        PropertyItems(0).Value = New Byte() {6, 0}
        bmp.SetPropertyItem(PropertyItems(0))

        bmp.Save(filename)
```

Should I note, the thumbnail offset of the picture doesn't change under XP too.

Any help appreciated!